# Messy but Working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've written the jQuery you'll see below for a little project I'm working on. It works perfectly and is all set, but, as you can see, it's messy and kind of...long winded.

I've tried a bunch of different ways to clean this up but I'm not just ninja-like enough to really neaten it up. Any advice? Thanks in advance guys!

```
  var colspan = $(".col header span"),
      rowspan = $(".row header span"),
      topspan = $(".top header span");

  var colh2 = $(".col header h2").h2width();
  var rowh2 = $(".row header h2").h2width();
  var toph2 = $(".top header h2").h2width();

  var colwidth = 820 - colh2;
  var rowwidth = 820 - rowh2;
  var topwidth = 820 - toph2;

  colspan.css({float: 'left', width: colwidth});
  rowspan.css({float: 'left', width: rowwidth});
  topspan.css({float: 'left', width: topwidth});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["col", "row", "top"].forEach(function (className) {
  var str = "." + className + " header";
  var h2s = document.querySelectorAll(str + " h2");
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll(str + " span");
  var width = 820 - h2width(h2s);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function (span) {
    span.style.float = "left";
    span.style.width = width;
  });
});
```

Because jQuery is always overkill.

Comment: Interesting. But please explain, why _always_.

Comment: @Tadeck performance. Everyone knows the DOM is 10-100x faster then jQuery.

Comment: I doubt it (I strongly believe not _everyone_ :)). And some people value readability and portability (across browsers), plus do not want to get into too much detail, as eg. John Resig (creator of jQuery) did in case of selector API you are using: http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/. Anyway I give you +1, because I think your answer is worth it.

Comment: Just as a clarification: I do not doubt in the performance difference, I doubt it is widely known. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Tadeck ah that, well the main difference is QSA is slow compared to gEBCN. That and the DOM4 Element API has some sugar for walking element trees.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this maybe? shorter but maybe not as well documented:

```
$(".col header span, .row header span, .top header span").each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        float: 'left',
        width: 820 - $(this).siblings("h2").width()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply get rid of the duplicate code:

```
$.each(['.col', '.row', '.top'], function(i, cls) {
    var width = $(cls + ' header h2').h2width();
    $(cls + ' header span').css({
        float: 'left',
        width: 820 - width
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$(".col header h2").h2width()` get re-calculated for each found element for `.col header span` selector?

Comment: If he has multiple of them then yes; I've edited the first example

Comment: oh man... you'rs is so much like mine. :S  You just need to use .each ot $(this) won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function:

```
function updateStyle(name){
   var headerSpan = $('.' + name + ' header span');
   var headerH2 = $('.' + name + ' header h2');
   headerSpan.css({float: 'left', width: 820 - headerH2.h2width()});
}

updateStyle('col');
updateStyle('row');
updateStyle('top');
```

Comment: this one is the most readable... however, I would suggest putting the function definition above the function calls just better readability... +1 if you do this :)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably rewrite your code in the following way:

```
var conts = {
    'col': jQuery('.col header'),
    'row': jQuery('.row header'),
    'top': jQuery('.top header')
};

jQuery.each(conts, function(index, val){
    val.find('span').css({
        'float': 'left',
        'width': 820-val.find('h2').h2width()
    });
});
```

This uses **caching the main elements** and then will **iterate on all of them** applying the similar actions.

See more information on [jQuery's .each() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

**EDIT:** Or even shorter:

```
jQuery('.col header, .row header, .top header').each(function(){
    var current = jQuery(this);
    current.find('span').css({
        'float': 'left',
        'width': 820 - current.find('h2').h2width()
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you no cache `jQuery(this)` >:(

Comment: @Raynos: Now you should be satisfied :)

Comment: Why `jQuery` and not `$`? Shorter is better.

Comment: Consider this: `$( 'span', this ).css({ 'float': 'left', 'width': 820 - $( 'h2', this ).h2width() });`. The `this` value is needed only for context, so there's no need to use `$(this)` at all.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Not always, `jQuery` works when `$` does, but `$` not always work when `jQuery` does. See [jQuery's .noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: @Tadeck `$` *works* inside a ready handler (which is where all jQuery code is supposed to be anyway). Just pass `$` as the first argument of the handler: `jQuery(function ( $ ) { /* all code here */ });`. (Of course, you only have to do this when you load other scripts that use the `$` name.) There is no argument to avoid `$` in favor of `jQuery`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas psh. "jQuery ready handlers" are fail. Everyone knows code goes just before the end of the `<body>` tag.